# How can I send the results from a form (with HTML, CSS, JavaScript, JQuery, etc.) to a Sharepoint Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, html, library

I am trying to create a form with html, css, javascript, jquery. Basically, what I would like to do is, when the user clicks on the "Submit" button, the values entered in the form will be send to a Sharepoint library (or another page with some specifics criteria)...

Each form submitted can contain names, files, photos and videos and will be displayed as a group of information (like a request ticket).

Can you help me?

I don't need a fancy form, I just want to pull the data submitted into another place within the SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a SharePoint list? You can add files/images as attachments to a list item.
Take a look at this Library(to help interacting with SharePoint):
https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/

You can use libraries like SemanticUI or BootStrap for building your form.